# Drawables Alpha changing while TabHost tabs switching

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I need to changing alpha of the drawables of my tabs when I click between my tabs in TabHost. I do it like this:

```
getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

                        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                            Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
                            Log.i("choosed activity", currentActivity.toString());
                            if (currentActivity instanceof LoginActivity) {
                                Log.i("current activity", "LoginActivity");
                                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login).setAlpha(255);
                                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.signup).setAlpha(80);
                                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.close).setAlpha(80);
                            }
                            if (currentActivity instanceof RegisterActivity) { 
                                Log.i("current activity", "RegisterActivity");
                                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login).setAlpha(80);
                                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.signup).setAlpha(255);
                                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.close).setAlpha(80);
                            }
});
```

Current Activity determines successfully, but alpha is changing only if I turn over the device. Tell me please how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try:`invalidate()` after setting your new alpha values